# REST API not working without port number in Eureka Server

Tags: java, spring-boot, microservices, spring-cloud, netflix-eureka

I have a Spring Cloud microservices application which has multiple services running independently and I'm using the Eureka service registry. All my micro services are registered into the Eureka server and all the client applications running on each port and IP address. Everything is fine.

I have the Vue front end application which is outside the spring cloud service and trying to access the Rest API's which are registered into the Eureka server.

Now the Rest API's only working with the port number of each client application that registered into the Eureka. For example, a market exchange service running on port 6005 and registered into the Eureka server and I'm trying to access the Rest API like this: `http://192.168.201.241:6005/market/exchange-rate/usd-cny` this is working fine.

But without port number Rest API not working Example: `http://192.168.201.241/market/exchange-rate/usd-cny`. I can't put port numbers on each individual micro service.  **How can I access the Rest API without the port number using the Eureka server IP address in local development?**

This is `application.properties` of Eureka server:

```
server.port=8761
eureka.instance.instance-id=${spring.cloud.client.ipAddress}:${server.port}
eureka.instance.hostname=${spring.cloud.client.ipAddress}
eureka.client.registerWithEureka=false
eureka.client.fetchRegistry=false
eureka.client.serviceUrl.defaultZone=http://${eureka.instance.hostname}:${server.port}/eureka/
eureka.server.enable-self-preservation=true
```

This is from Eureka client

```
eureka.client.serviceUrl.defaultZone=http://localhost:8761/eureka/
```

This is my Eureka Dashboard:
[image]

Comment: You need to use service-exchange-trade rather than an IP address

Comment: I'm having more than 8 services, and one common front end application, It's hard to give the api gateway name for each individual Rest API's. Any other possible ways?

Comment: I guess I don't understand how your applications are arranged

Answer (score 0):

You have to implement an API gateway along with service registry, for example ZUUL api gateway and execute the request through gateway. The url will look something like this `http://{host}:{port of api gateway}/{name of service to be invoked}/{path to resource}`
Gateway will takecare of calling it to actual port and service which is registered with service registry